# Que hacer con usuarios mal agradecidos

Tags: discusión

Si bien es cierto que esto no es un problema existencial para la humanidad como lo son el cambio climático y el agujero de la capa de ozono, para el gremio de stackoverflow si lo es.

Resulta que llevo varios días intercambiando con un usuario sobre una respuesta que le di a una pregunta que realizó. Les confieso que ha sido desgastante atender a este usuario, he tenido que contar hasta 100 varias veces para no mandarlo bien lejos, el mismo ha demostrado una falta de interés y torpeza que si tuviera el privilegio del martillo de Thor yo mismo le cerraba la pregunta. Este usuario tiene la característica de no marcar como aceptadas las respuestas que se le dan y la de sacarte de quicio por no entender nada de lo que le explicas. Yo pregunto se puede hacer algo con estos usuarios tan despreocupados?

Aquí les dejo el enlace al perfil del usuario: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/334899/daniel-navarro

Este usuario ha hecho como 6 preguntas y casi todas han sido respondidas con gran calidad, y en varias ocasiones se le ha pedido que marque las respuestas como aceptada, a lo cual ha hecho caso omiso, no se si por torpeza o porque le da lo mismo.

Este es el enlace a la pregunta que le respondí: [¿Como ocultar una columna de un DataGridView si el CheckBox esta en su propiedad OnChecked y mostrarla si esta en su propiedad Checked en C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/610013/como-ocultar-una-columna-de-un-datagridview-si-el-checkbox-esta-en-su-propiedad/610023#610023)

Comment: Hoy me alegro si encuentro una pregunta cercanamente respondible, que me acepten las respuestas o el puntaje perdió todo sentido con el volumen de preguntas que hay en la actualidad. En algún momento yo propuse que pasado un tiempo y si no existía respuesta aceptada, automáticamente se marcara la respuesta con mayor puntaje, y así se premiara a las personas que invierten tiempo en responder, ahora creo que estamos más cerca que el sitio cierre a que exista alguna mejora en cualquier ámbito.

Comment: Como te han dicho, lo mejor es ignorar al usuario en cuestión. No pierdes nada. Por otro lado, yo respondo por el simple hecho de escribir una respuesta y quizá ayudar. No me importa tanto como antes que tan desagradecido es el usuario, también es una buena vía pensarlo de ese modo.

Comment: Tanto lío por una pregunta que merece ser cerrada. Pero en fin.

Comment: Lo primero es tratar de ayudar al usuario a formular de mejor forma sus preguntas, si respondes este tipo de preguntas, probablemente el usuario probablemente no va a valorar tu respuesta o tal vez no entienda lo que tiene que hacer. Esa pregunta debería ser cerrada, te sugiero leer [ask]. El OP decide si acepta o no tu respuesta.

Comment: @Jorgesys  y porque debe leer el "como preguntar" si el está respondiendo ??? :S

Comment: @Yussef porque parece que `Japv` no tiene claro cómo debe lucir una pregunta bien formulada. ¿Qué hay de malo en volver a leer [ask] y en volver a hacer el [tour]? O incluso, ¿qué hay de malo en que te sugieran que lo hagas? ¿O acaso es que las respuestas van totalmante desconectadas de las preguntas? Parece que para ti lo importante es únicamente responder, yo te pregunto ¿existirían respuestas sin preguntas?

Comment: Nada, nada, no, si, no

Comment: @Yussef para que conozca como se debe realizar una pregunta en el sitio, y antes de responder pueda ayudar al usuario a mejorar su pregunta, para que la pregunta cumpla el objetivo de ser útil para la comunidad, no únicamente para el que pregunta.

Comment: @Jorgesys Vale, entiendo y me parece perfecto lo que dices. Solo que me parece más natural leer la ayuda de "como responder" para responder

Comment: @Jorgesys, el usuario es un vago en casi todas las preguntas que ha echo se le ha pedido que acepte la respuesta, por otra parte esa pregunta estaba más clara que el agua, no había que dar tantas vueltas para responderla, el usuario es el que no esta cumpliendo con lo establecido y se está ganando una mala reputación, tú como moderador deberías mandarle un correo privado y decirle que en stackoverflow los agradecimientos se dan marcando respuestas, ponle un conteo de protección, por falta de advertencia no ha sido

Comment: @Japv en realidad, el centro de ayuda no menciona que aceptar la respuesta sea obligatorio, de hecho, se espera que el usuario acepte la respuesta más util, por lo que estaría en su derecho a esperar algo mejor (se que este no es el caso de este usuario). Y casi nadie parece ver esto como algo que requiera tanto como para que un moderador diamantado intervenga.

Comment: @DanteS. es verdad que no es obligatorio pero es una buena práctica y es lo recomendado por la comunidad, lo menos que puede hacer la moderación es escribirle y decirle que no se está comportando como debiera,  ese usuario es un descaradito, y además, es tan torpe que hasta el móvil escribió en un lugar público donde no conoce a nadie, pero eso sí es su problema

Comment: @Japv Te sugiero evitar faltar al respeto a los usuarios del sitio, en este caso lo recomendable es ayudar a nuevos usuarios a realizar preguntas y respuestas de acuerdo a lo establecido en el sitio, incluso  puedes compartirle el [tour], para que entienda un poco mejor el funcionamiento del sitio, esto antes de responder y molestarte porque no te dió puntuación positiva.

Comment: @Japv El OP decide si acepta tu respuesta, si vota únicamente +1 o si vota -1, el decide incluso si valora tu respuesta, no se le puede obligar, ni es algo por lo cual un moderador le tenga que llamar la atención, pero faltar al respeto es algo que no debe tener cabida en este sitio.

Comment: @Jorgesys ese usuario le falta el respeto a todos, y bien que si puedes dejarle un escrito como en muchas otras ocasiones Uds mismos han hecho, pero bueno parece que no quieres trabajar, en el sitio tampoco tiene cabida el abuso de poder, eso es peor y ya hoy conmigo te has equivocado bastante, y no se trata del puntaje sino de la indolencia ante lo mal hecho

Comment: Pero además @Jorgesys que paso que de pronto has votado negativo mis últimas publicaciones en meta, cual es el dolor, pq actúas en modo venganza, mantente al margen

Comment: @Japv el usuario te falto al respeto por no votar o aceptar tu respuesta como solución?, que sucedería si este usuario te votará negativo? Quieres que se suspenda al usuario por no votar? hahaha, Por cierto, te sugiero evitar amenazas.

Comment: @Jorgesys deja de estar a la defensiva, a ti nadie te ha amenazado, el usuario le faltó el respeto a todos los que amablemente le comentaron que acepte una respuesta y el hizo caso omiso, no se trata de mí, no personalices, por cierto en qué momento pedí que suspendieran al usuario, lo más que pedí es que como moderador le dejaras un comentario, no exageres por favor, que lo de suspenderlo lo acabas de decir tu

Comment: @Jorgesys acaba de entender que no se trata de si me voto o no me voto, se trata de su actitud descuidada con los demás

Comment: Si, no se le puede llamar la atención, su actitud al respecto no es agresiva. Pero si puedes preferir ignorarlo y no responderle

Comment: Lo que te deberías plantear es por qué respondes las preguntas: ¿Es por puntos, reputación, etc.? ¿Es por intentar mejorar el banco de conocimiento del sitio? ¿Es por que quieres hacer tu obra buena del día? ¿Es por ayudar a otro que venga después con el mismo problema? ¿Es por que el que te den las gracias te hace sentir mejor?  ¿Es por devolver la ayuda que te han dado antes? Un consejo: no dejes recaer lo que te hace feliz/infeliz en otras personas, sino tu felicidad no dependerá de tí únicamente. Haz que la acción sea lo que te hace feliz, no la recompensa ni la reacción de otras personas.

Answer (score 4):

Para mi en lo personal la forma de actuar suele ser más simple:

1. Lo primero que hago es **dejarle un comentario** resaltando sus errores, no le digo que vaya a leer nada por que ya otros normalmente lo han hecho.
2. **Voto la pregunta para cierre**, ya que lo primero que debe hacer el usuario es demostrar la intencion de usar correctamente la plataforma.
3. Si el usuario **denota interes se le guia** mediante comentario a mejorar su pregunta. y asi solicitar la re-apertura de la misma. el siguiente nivel si entra al chat entonces se le explica como funciona la comunidad y otras cosas adicionales ...
4. si el **usuario es despreocupado y no le interesa su pregunta se quedara Cerrada** y con el tiempo el mismo sistema ocultara/eliminara la pregunta.

**Notas:**

No tiene sentido usar el sistema de votos (negativos) en una pregunta cerrada o en una mala pregunta... el sistema se encargara de ella en el punto #4.

Excepcionalmente solo usaria el voto de forma positiva, para equilibrar la pregunta si tiene votos negativos y considero que ese voto fue mal intencionado o no tiene sentido (Preguntas con votos negativos sin ningun comentario) ...

ESTE METODO le llamo LA PURGA. y ya varios han pasado por ese aro en el sitio como el compañero [Yussef](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/301324/yussef)

hacer algo mas o algo diferente, es perdida de tiempo para mi ... si veo que hay algo mal en general y no con un usuario aislado intento traerlo a meta ... a ver si a la comunidad le interesa el algo ... cosa que muy poco suele pasar ...

Comment: Es un buen manejo para los casos de una pregunta "mal formulada". Pero en este caso particular, el usuario en cuestión no hizo nada para que se pueda cerrar su pregunta, lo que invalida el paso 4 para esta situación.

Comment: En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/575012/158880), intenté guiar a un usuario a una forma más conveniente de lograr su objetivo, me dijo que evite "hacer algo que no aporta solución", y cuando vió por mi siguiente comentario que me perdió, se disculpó. Ahora tiene dos respuestas y no agradeció de ninguna manera.  Yo creo que "se fue con la respuesta entre las garras". Pero no podemos hacer nada contra este usuario, ya que casi no fue agresivo y su pregunta está bien formulada.

Comment: cuando los usuarios se niegan a cooperar entran mas facil en el punto 4 ... ya que el usuario no provee la informacion adecuada ...

Comment: Eso es verdad, y aunque igualmente no es el caso de este usuario ni el de el que mencioné en el comentario anterior, si aplica a casos generales.

Comment: @DanteS. yo creo que si encaja pero para nuevas preguntas ... ser un poquito mas exigente con este tipo de usuarios ... no cuesta nada ... arbitrariamente no podemos hacer nada ... pero si se le puede comensar a explicar en los comentarios que se espera de el como usuarios ...

Answer (score 3):

Lamento lo sucedido, espero puedas encontrar tranquilidad de alguna manera. Con respecto a tu publicación, vamos por partes estimado:

> Resulta que llevo varios días intercambiando con un usuario sobre una respuesta que le di a una pregunta que realizó.

Si es entorno a la misma pregunta y/o respuesta, y todo sigue dando vueltas sin progreso, no tiene buena pinta. Encontrarse con el mismo árbol en el bosque es porque uno está perdido.

> Les confieso que ha sido desgastante atender a este usuario, he tenido que contar hasta 100 varias veces para no mandarlo bien lejos, el mismo ha demostrado una falta de interés y torpeza

Aquí te invito a que hagas una pausa, las acciones de la gente están fuera de tu control, por lo tanto, lo más sano luego de haber hablado es dejarlas de lado; en su momento también me ocurrió algo similar con un usuario, irónicamente en ese perfil decía "especialista" y pues... ¿para qué perder tiempo con gente así?

> que si tuviera el privilegio del martillo de Thor yo mismo le cerraba la pregunta.

Esto sí puedes hacer, aunque sin cierre directo porque eres usuario común y silvestre como quien redacta este mensaje, simplemente una votación para la cierre de la pregunta.

> Este usuario tiene la característica de no marcar como aceptadas las respuestas que se le dan y la de sacarte de quicio por no entender nada de lo que le explicas.

Personalmente, llega un momento donde te aburres de pedirles que marquen una respuesta como aceptada, tengo varias respuestas y varias siguen sin marcarse como aceptadas, tampoco tienen votos y a estas alturas de la vida, me da lo mismo, a alguien le será de ayuda y ya.

Hay gente que tiene problemas de aprendizaje serios, también hay gente que tienen problemas de lectura serios; nosotros estamos de voluntarios, de colaboradores, no estamos de docentes o tutores exclusivos ¿o sí? La responsabilidad de aprender es de quien pregunta, ¿verdad? Es bonito cuando ayudas a la gente de corazón y la gente te responde con esa misma amabilidad. Lamento saber que estás lidiando con un usuario malagradecido, quizás la vida de ese usuario ha de ser tan complicada y triste que la gratitud está fuera de su vida, espero estar equivocado y espero que ese usuario pueda darse cuenta que el tiempo que recibe de manera altruista merece respeto y aprecio, la experiencia de todo desarrollador viene por efecto de adquisición de conocimientos, práctica y dedicación de tiempo, un malagradecido es incapaz de ver y reconocer estos elementos.

> Yo pregunto se puede hacer algo con estos usuarios tan despreocupados?

Se puede poner un comentario, otra alternativa es evitar responder y comentar lo que ellos realicen. Hay ciertos usuarios que publican una pregunta y por ser ellos los que preguntan, prefiero dejar esa pregunta para que otro usuario le responda, de este modo la paz mental interna se mantiene en buen estado y el tiempo que es altamente valioso, se lo utiliza en actividades que generen bienestar.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, esta respuesta no intenta justificar al AP acusado de *mal agradecido*, tampoco quitarle mérito al Post de `Japv`.

A veces encontramos usuarios que no les interesa el sistema gamificado de Stack Overflow. Con esto me refiero a que no les interesa participar en la aceptación y/o votación. Sólo vienen buscando ayuda y les basta un simple comentario de agradecimiento o a veces ni eso.

**¿Podemos hacer algo al respecto?**

Claramente no, no podemos **obligar** a nadie a usar el sitio de la forma que se espera que lo usen. Por lo tanto, lo mejor es pasar página y continuar.

**¿Se pudo evitar el sentimiento expresado por `Japv`?**

Creo que definitivamente se pudo evitar. `Japv` es un usuario con más de 10k de reputación, para llegar allí ha tenido que recorrer un largo trecho, por lo cual alguna experiencia tiene en el sitio y supongo (suposición sustentada en la reputación solamente) que sabe diferenciar entre una pregunta mal formulada y una bien formulada.

En el caso del AP expuesto en esta pregunta, si revisamos sus publicaciones, vemos que un comentario tipo "me funcionó" le es suficiente para darse por satisfecho:

> Gracias Yussef, con el Evento que me indicas, me funciono perfectamente, a lo requerido, muchas gracias su conocimiento ayuda a muchos [(link)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/600521/como-pasar-el-contenido-de-la-fila-selecciona-al-los-textbox-con-c#comment1060705_600525)

Ahora, volviendo a la pregunta que `Japv`respondió, y usando mi propio comentario en este Post de Meta:

> Tanto lío por una pregunta que merece ser cerrada. Pero en fin. [(link)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5608/que-hacer-con-usuarios-mal-agradecidos#comment25172_5608)

es de destacar que la pregunta en si misma tiene defectos de forma.

Si yo leo una pregunta que dice: *tengo esta consulta, ..., tengo estas columnas, ..., **la idea** es que..., ¿cómo se hace?*, para mi, (y seguramente para muchos usuarios del sitio) a esta pregunta le falta algo.

Le falta un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), que indique lo que el usuario ha intentado hacer para resolver su propio problema.

La pregunta respondida por `Japv` carece de ello y sin embargo ha recibido incluso un voto positivo.

Tal vez `Japv` tiene mucha experiencia y puede crear el código que responde a la pregunta, la cual carece de código en absoluto. O en esta era de las IA, el mismo ha sido generado mediante alguna de ellas, cosa que no es tan difícil.

Entonces, ¿qué motiva el Post en cuestión?. Según mi punto de vista, (y espero equivocarme profundamente), `Japv`, como algunos otros usuarios, van respondiendo todo lo que se atraviese y tenga algo de sentido, y lo hacen por la puntuación (sino no habría publicado esto en Meta).

No digo que hacerlo por la puntuación esté mal, yo mismo respondo por la puntuación. Pero lo que definitivamente no hago, teniendo ya más de 10K de reputación, es responder preguntas mal formuladas.

Mi recomendación a `Japv` y a todos los usuarios que sientan esto que ha expresado `Japv` en su Post, es que se detengan a pensar un poco en el tipo de preguntas que están leyendo y si las mismas tienen el formato mínimo requerido para este sitio. De esta forma van a evitar toparse con estas situaciones.

Hace poco en el chat de Stack Overflow en Español comentaba algo al respecto, sobre la necesidad de mantener de alguna manera la calidad de las publicaciones, que no se refiere exclusivamente a las respuestas sino a las preguntas primordialmente.

Si queremos que el sitio siga siendo de utilidad, debemos fomentar la calidad de preguntas y respuestas.

Más de una vez se ha respondido preguntas cuyo título dice: *"Ayuda con [etiqueta de lenguaje]"* o similares. Suelo obviar de entrada ese tipo de preguntas, y, en el mejor de los casos les dejo un comentario al respecto.

Ser meticuloso, metódico y coherente se logra con mucha paciencia, y si entendemos la finalidad del sitio y sus normas, reglas y/o sugerencias de uso, es muy probable que estemos ayudando a mantener la calidad del mismo.

Comment: Trolcito, publique en meta pq no es la primera vez que me pasa, la respuesta es mia como todas las otras que doy no de una IA ,  y respondo cuando las preguntas me parecen atractivas independientemente de los puntos, aunque si, es cierto, me encanta recibir puntos, pero no me quita el sueño así que ese párrafo no te quedó muy bien, simplemente la torpeza de ese usuario superó la de otros con los que me he encontrado en la comunidad, y mira tanto lío y al final me dedicaste una respuesta y muy bien redactada, gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: En WinForms muchas veces es mejor que pongan una imagen que el código, la pregunta era perfectamente respondible tanto así que Japv pudo hacerlo en pocas líneas de código, sin inventar supuestos.

Comment: @Yussef en ningún momento dije nada de una imagen. ¿Dónde está el intento del AP? En la imagen? Pero nada, cada quien según su capacidad.

Comment: No hay intento, y evidentemente la pregunta hubiera estado mejor con algo de código.  Pero tampoco hay que darle tantas vueltas a una pregunta que se responde con 2 líneas de código

Comment: @Yussef, [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/610374/trabajando-funciones-con-argumentos-opcionales) también se responde en pocas lineas de código. No le des vueltas y responde al AP. Descuidar la calidad hace que el sitio deje de ser relvante, y según tus propias palabras: ***ahora creo que estamos más cerca que el sitio cierre a que exista alguna mejora en cualquier ámbito***. Empieza por mejorar tu forma de razonar sobre la calidad de las preguntas.

Comment: @ElTroll gracias por tener una capacidad tan grande, eres un faro

Comment: @ElTroll Esa pregunta es distinta, es una tarea académica y ha sido cerrada, la otra es una funcionalidad bien atómica y concisa y que ya en 7 días no ha sido cerrada.

Comment: Tu induces que la "calidad" de las preguntas afectan a la relevancia del sitio. Estoy en desacuerdo, cuando comenzó SO y SOes eran muchos más laxos para permitir preguntas y solo cuando alcanzaron masa critica se pusieron más estrictos, lo que ocasionó un descenso en la visitas. Así que para mi los hechos demuestran lo contrario.

Comment: Vale, puedes estar en desacuerdo, pero lo "estricto" sigue allí, cuando lo cambien, pues nos adaptaremos, de momento es lo que hay. Las propuestas de cambio han existido desde hace mucho tiempo y las relacionadas con el nivel "estricto" nunca han sido aceptadas.

Comment: Yo respondo por interés en la pregunta en si, como javp. Ignoro las "normas", motivado por: "Que normas debo hacer cumplir? Este sitio tiene favoritismos y escribe nada en piedra. La comunidad hace lo que cree es correcto y se equivoca". Así que yo también hago lo que creo correcto.

Comment: @DanteS. opinamos igual, yo también hago lo que creo correcto, y me ciño a las normas del sitio. Seguiré votando negativo cuando considere que hace falta, seguiré mandando a leer [ask], [answer] y a relizar el [tour] y seguiré votando a cierre las preguntas de baja calidad. Y seguiré dejando comentarios a quienes vea que hacen caso omiso de las normas.

Comment: Que crees hacer lo correcto y recomiendes esos links (que son un poco falsos, pero no se puede hacer nada con eso), me parece bien. Pero a que normas te refieres? A las normas implicitas de la comunidad? O a tus propias normas?

Comment: Jamás he hablado de *mis propias normas*, en cambio tú si lo has sugerido diciendo que **"ignoras las normas"**. Yo ante la duda, repaso las normas o simplemente paso de accionar para no equivocarme. Pero lo que no hago es saltarme las normas a posta o porque me de igual.

Comment: Si, leí mejor tu comentario. Supongo que sos de los pocos que respetan las normas escritas.

Comment: Para clarificar, yo NO creo que todas las preguntas deberían valer, hay preguntas que claramente deben ser cerradas. Creo que cuando participamos en un sitio debemos cumplir lar normas. El punto es como interpretamos esas normas y el espíritu de ellas.  Yo siempre intento interpretarlas en favor del usuario, rescatar lo bueno de su pregunta, porque si me pongo a buscar detalles es que hay que cerrar el 80% de las preguntas y me quedo corto.

Comment: Por ejemplo en este caso tu dices que no hay código y yo leo en los mismos enlaces que has puesto: **No todas las preguntas se benefician del código incluido**

Comment: A mi me parece perfecto que tu operes en el sitio como te parezca (dentro del contexto de las normas), tu quieres ser super estricto bien por ti, quieres dejar mensajes bien también. Ahora los que pensamos distinto tenemos el mismo derecho. Entonces si yo o Japv pensamos que la pregunta es aceptable y la pregunta está abierta y sigue abierta, pues no veo porque no podamos responder

Answer (score 0):

Voy a responder porque a veces tiendo a interesarme por algunas preguntas, ya que figuran un reto para mi, es más en estos días hasta pedí que reabrieran mi chat para ayudar a un user con su duda.

Una vez la pregunta ha sido resuelta invito amablemente al OP a aceptar o incluso responder su pregunta para que esta no quede "huérfana". Esa siempre ha sido una buena forma de "incentivar" a los OP de no dejar sin respuesta aceptada una pregunta.

Pero también, me tomo el tiempo de ver el perfil de quien solicita mi ayuda. Y debo decir que no ha sido solo una vez en donde me ha tocado decir: "En vista que jamás das por aceptadas ninguna de las respuestas que te dan, me temo que no puedo ayudarte, si quieres mi ayuda debes aceptar las respuestas a preguntas anteriores".

Y como usuario, estas en la total libertad de hacerlo, si al OP no le gusta, se puede ir a ver gansitos si quiere, pero obligados a dar soporte no estamos.

Ahora, es de ver algo también, si decides ayudar a alguien es de manera desinteresada, no buscando algo a cambio (aunque sean unos puntos de reputación) ya que ese es el sentido de sitios como este.

Así que @javp te invito a que encuentres un punto medio entre todo y aceptes las cosas que ya pasaron y aprendas de ellas. Recuerda que cuando ayudas a alguien tu también aprendes algo nuevo o refrescas lo que ya sabes.

¿Pero se puede hacer algo? Creo que no hay una directriz especifica para este tipo de usuarios. Yo hace mucho propuse en que si una pregunta no tenia respuesta aceptada se podía hacer como una "votación" para dar por "aceptada" la respuesta con más votos pero vinieron muchos a decirme que los puntos no son nada, que es algo que no se necesita, que la reputación no es importante, que el OP decide si aceptar algo o no blablalba...

Yo si creo que debería existir un método para dar por aceptada una respuesta pero dudo que se haga, más como están las cosas ahora, dudo que la admón. de SE se preocupe por cambios tan banales como este.

Comment: Yo siempre que veo un comentario del tipo "Gracias me funcionó tu respuesta", invito al usuario a aceptarla, aun que no sea mía. Quizás si todos nos preocupáramos de eso, de la misma manera que existe una preocupación cuando la pregunta no sigue las normas, habrían menos casos.

Comment: En efecto @Yussef. A mi no me gustan las preguntas huérfanas y hago lo que tu dices, pero es obvio que no ando en todas las preguntas para "arriar" a la gente a aceptar una respuesta. Pero la opción que yo he propuesto (dos veces) también es buena. Una forma de aceptar respuestas válidas a preguntas "huérfanas" 

Comment: @Yussef también he hecho eso que dices, pero bueno hay quien no tiene arreglo